# glance image-create fails with error Unable to establish connection

Tags: networking, virtualization, openstack, disk-image

I installed openstack using conjure-up(single node installation - all services of openstack on one server, this is for experimental purposes) and then was able to upload couple of sample images as follows

```
glance image-create --name "xenial-cloud1" --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --file xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img
```

the size of this image is around 280MB.

Then I proceeded to upload an image of size 12GB which is a ubuntu 16.04 Desktop image with Hawkbit installed on it.

**glance image-create --name "ubuntu-16-hawkbit-qcow2" --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --file hawkbit-image.qcow2 --progress**

It failed at 70% giving the below error

> Error finding address for http://ip_of_
>   glance:9292/v2/images/7dc43b2a-5d42-41fc-acbe-16493f0d8395/file:
>   Unable to establish connection to http://:9292/v2/images/7dc43b2a-5d42-41fc-acbe-16493f0d8395/file

after this even when I try to upload a smaller size image it doesnt work.

All the services are up and running when I check status with the command
**juju status**

Even glance related commands like
**glance image-list** also give the same error

**Error finding address for http://ip_of_glance:9292/versions: Unable to establish connection to http://ip_of_glance:9292/versions**

Glance service is listening on port 9292 , i sshed into the glance node and ran

```
ubuntu@juju-64a1f1-4:~$ sudo netstat -plnt | grep ':9292'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9292            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1682/haproxy
tcp6       0      0 :::9292                 :::*                    LISTEN      1682/haproxy
```

So am not sure, whats the problem. Any help to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Note: This is the first time I am using openstack, so am a novice, please bear if ive missed out giving certain details or gone about things in the wrong fashion.

when running **lxd init** before installing openstack using conjure-up, 
we chose 27GB as the size of the loop device(it was the default one indicated)
**storage backend as zfs**

UPDATE: When I set the

> default_store = file

in /etc/glance/glance-api.conf

I am able to upload an image which is really small like 13MB or so but a bigger image throws me an error described here : https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/27033/image-storage-media-is-full/, thats because I don't have enough space on **filesystem_store_datadir = /var/lib/glance/images/**

I figured that my initial default_store was set to rbd after I finished installation using conjure-up, which is related to ceph. Also I've notice that ceph.service is active but in exited state, I tried to restart it but it wont leave the exited state

> ceph.service                            loaded active exited    LSB:
>   Start Ceph distributed file system daemons at boot time

If I can get this to be working, I'm sure things will return to normal from where I left off when I could upload two images successfully (when file store was set to rbd)

Is it possible to increase the space in /var/lib/glance/images/ post installation or even point **filesystem_store_datadir** to another machines path which has space on it ?

Comment: I was able to mount a location in my server which had space , gave that path in the glance api conf file and was able to store created images in the file system

Answer (score 0):

allow connections from "ip_of_glance to port `9292/tcp` and `9292/udp`.